# Two queries I thought the same are returning different results

Tags: sql, postgresql

so I'm apparently not thinking about this correctly. I am using postgres. I was checking to see if my database had any duplicate `(latitude, longitude)` pairs. To do so I was just getting the count:

```
SELECT SUM(dups.inner_count) 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT latitude, longitude, COUNT(*) as inner_count 
    FROM company 
    GROUP BY latitude, longitude 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) as dups;
```

This query returned different results than this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM company 
WHERE (latitude, longitude) 
IN 
  (
    SELECT latitude, longitude 
    FROM company 
    GROUP BY latitude, longitude 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  );
```

I felt like these should have returned the same so now I'm confused. I haven't had my coffee yet so I feel like I'm probably just doing something stupid. Are these different?

Comment: The difference may be due to `NULL` values, which the first will count but not hte second.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's totally it. add `latitude is not null` to the first and the sums are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, thanks to @GordonLinoff, in `postgres`:

> An `IN` statement will be parsed identically to field=val1 or field=val2
>   or field=val3. Putting a null in there will boil down to field=null
>   which won't work.

So the first query had ~88000 null `latitude` and `longitude`'s which weren't being factored into the second query. I'm not crazy. You learn something new every day

Comment: This is not specific to Postgres, this is how NULL processing is defined in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is returning the sum of all of the inner_count values being returned by your sub query; your second example is a count of how many rows are being returned by your sub query. They are requesting to different things so it would be expected that they return two different values.

Comment: But the query look for the same things.

Comment: Look carefully at what is summing